# convert batch of pdf to text using pdftools

Tags: r, pdf, batch-processing

I'm tying to convert 1000 pdfs to text for data analysis. I'm using the package pdftools.

I have been able to convert 2 pdf using the following code:

```
library(pdftools)
file_list <- list.files('pdf', full.names = TRUE, pattern = 'pdf')

for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
  temp <- pdf_text(file_list[i])
  temp <- tolower(temp)

  file_name = paste(file_list[i], '.txt')
  sink(file_name)
  cat(temp)
  sink()

}
```

but when I add more than 2 I get the following error:

```
" Error in poppler_pdf_text(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : PDF parsing failure."
```

also, I would like the final text file to be only "file_name.txt" right now i'm getting "file_name.pdf .txt"

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
library(pdftools)
library(purrr)

setwd("/tmp/test")

file_list <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE, pattern = '.pdf$')

s_pdf_text <- safely(pdf_text) # helps catch errors

walk(file_list, ~{                                     # iterate over the files

  res <- s_pdf_text(.x)                                # try to read it in
  if (!is.null(res$result)) {                          # if successful

    message(sprintf("Processing [%s]", .x))

    txt_file <- sprintf("%stxt", sub("pdf$", "", .x))  # make a new filename

    unlist(res$result) %>%                             # cld be > 1 pg (which makes a list)
      tolower() %>%                                    
      paste0(collapse="\n") %>%                        # make one big text block with line breaks
      cat(file=txt_file)                               # write it out

  } else {                                             # if not successful
    message(sprintf("Failure converting [%s]", .x))    # show a message
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks@hrbrmstr! However, I'm able to convert only 20 out of the 1000 pdf.  I have tried using another code (see below) however with that code the txt. file I'm getting are corrupting characters (all my files are in Spanish, so i have multiple special characters ´´ñ, í, ó, ú"  and I need all the characters to be lower case)

Comment: pdf_files <- list.files(path = paste(getwd(), '/pdf', sep = ''),
                            pattern = 'pdf',
                            full.names = TRUE)
    if( length(pdf_files) > 0 ){
     
      for(i in pdf_files){
        system(
          paste(
            paste('"', getwd(), '/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', sep = ''), 
            paste0('"', i, '"')),
          wait = FALSE)
      }
    }   
  cat( '\nConversion to text complete.\n\n' )

Comment: Unfortunately it's not really possible for folks to write al the code for you. The `stringi` package has `stri_trans_tolower()` which helps with translations from different character sets.